# How can i display asp.net html style?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> I has create view for public ActionResult Product and I want it shows as html and not as text

```
`<div class="grid product">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
         <div class="product-image">
             <img src="~/Images/@Model.image">
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
         <h1>@Model.ProductName</h1>
         <h2>Price: @Model.price</h2>
         <div class="description">
             @Model.Detail > **It shows text and i want its content to be html**
         </div>
     </div>
</div>`
```

> and this is what it shows at **@Model.Detail**

```
[show on website][1]


[html code][2]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfGP0.png

And this is how it shows in the html file

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOmzu.png
```

> Is there a way for me to remove the " so that the content in @Model.Detail becomes html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default output is HTML-encoded by the ASP.NET Framework.  This is **a good thing** because improperly encoded output can easily lead to [XSS vulnerabilities](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/).  (As well as just ugly bugs and UI issues if users are allowed to modify HTML content.)

If this isn't a concern for you and you are confident of the validity of your content, you can force it to not be encoded by using [`HtmlHelper.Raw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw):

```
<div class="description">
    @Html.Raw(Model.Detail)
</div>
```